# How to organize the features export modules

Tags: drupal-7

As we go along with features export, its being a mess. What I have been doing so far is every module with have another module that contains the feature exports. Let say their is module 'test' and it has some variable settings and I exported it via features. I will have another module name 'test_features_export' or something like that which contains the component associated with that module. But in some cases, the component can be too generic like 'role' which can be associated with multiple modules. Then its issue to bind to any specific features where it is meaningful.

So my question is , is there any better way to organize the features exports modules ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Store completed feature in feature-module but not only settings or only variables or only permissions.
2. Use dependencies in feature-module to build more complex features.
3. Take a look at https://drupal.org/project/apps. It's an upper level to features.